# SQL: Concat Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, concatenation, repeat

We have this argument:

```
UPDATE `categories` SET `categories_image`= concat(`categories_image`,'.gif')
WHERE `parent_id` IN (1476,1477)
```

That work but the '.gif' come repetitive

Ex: I would like this : Crystals.gif but the result come like that Crystals.gif.gif.gif.gif.gif.gif...

Do you have a idea to resolve that.

thank

Answer (score 2):

Use `like`:

```
UPDATE `categories` 
    SET `categories_image`= concat(`categories_image`,'.gif')
    WHERE `parent_id` IN (1476, 1477) AND
          categories_image NOT LIKE '%.gif';
```

Comment: `'.gif'` part repeats, because you are executing the SQL query several times. It is added as many times as you execute the query. So this seems like the proper solution - to check if `'.gif'` has already been added

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `categories` 
SET `categories_image`= CONVERT(nvarchar,`categories_image`) + '.gif' 
WHERE `parent_id` IN (1476,1477)
```